# nginx config separate location and under the location

Tags: nginx

below code is my nginx config, now if I visit `location /images/article1` it will return 404 not found,   how to solve this?

e.g  location a define `/a/` root to folder and  location b define `/a/b` to alias another folder

I did test commented `location ~ ^/(images/|javascripts/|stylesheets/|fonts)` then will show properly.

```
location ~ ^/(images/|javascripts/|stylesheets/|fonts) {
root /Sites/domain/app/assets;
access_log off;
expires max;
}

location /images/article1 {
alias /Sites/sub.domain/app/assets/images/article1;
access_log off;
expires max;
}
```

and

```
location /images/sub {
root /Sites/sub.domain/app/assets;
access_log off;
expires max;
}
```

and

```
location /sub/(images/|fonts) {
root /Sites/sub.domain/app/assets;
access_log off;
expires max;
}
```

Comment: I think you should reformulate, I can't understand your question, and i doubt to be the only one.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location Matching regexes are preferred to fixed strings unless `=` is used. Matching regexes are preferred in the order they appear in the config.

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek  thanks , then what should I do if I try to define another location under the same url  e.g  location a define `/a/` root and  location b define `/a/b` to alias

Answer (score 1):

The regex location takes precedence over a prefix location unless the `^~` modifier is used. Try:

```
location ^~ /images/article1 { ... }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Thanks for reply. and what if I wanna the second location is root to another folder not just alias  still use ^~ ?   I update in question